# In Beat Hazard, how do I earn perk unlocks?

Tags: beat-hazard

At first, I thought it was 1 per rank gained; however, skipping about 7 ranks in one go still only got me a single unlock. Now, I'm actually at the maximum rank, but half the perks are still locked.

So, how *are* they unlocked?

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug.

Comment: Did you have progress from before the update? If you did, then they gave you an option to reset your progress, which the ingame help said would make unlocks easier. All I can think of is that you didn't choose to do that, so you're now at max rank and have to perhaps "rank up" more to unlock.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Haven't played a single second of Classic, and I'm not to keen on resetting my stats at this point.

Comment: Maximum rank as in...? As far as I've played, you'll hit Veteran and then start getting Veteran 2, 3 etc.

Comment: @DJPirtu Elite. I assumed that was the last rank since it's the last listed, but apparently there's still Elite 2 and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just confirmed that Beat Hazard Ultra works just like the old one. The "last rank" is Elite, but after you reach it, you can still make progress. The next ranks will be Elite 2, Elite 3 and so on, each requiring 10,000,000 points after reaching the last. Looking at the forums, I see that somebody's at level 30 by now. So, lots of time to get the perks as you're rather unlikely to get more thank one rank at the time at that point.

Comment: Okay, so skipping ranks really does waste unlocks and now they're 10 million points each. Oh well.

Comment: Well, I play on Hardcore and it doesn't really make a big difference. I used to get an unlock after every one or two songs. Now I get an unlock after every three or four songs.